# Youtube API - How can i retrieve multiple videos in one request using VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

This question has been killing me, what i want to do is retrieve more than one video from YouTube in one request. now these videos do not belong to a playlist i just want to specify random video ids and request the feed from YouTube using the video ids specified.

I have heard and looked into batch processing with YouTube but i can not find any resource that gives any explanation on how to create batch processing in VB.Net for retrieving videos.

I have seen some flash and PHP code that can answer this question but i need the functionality for VB.Net application.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Comment: Point us to the php code that answers this question. It may be easier to show you how to convert that to VB.NET.

Comment: @MichaelPryor, hi, here is the thread i found http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/youtube-api-gdata@googlegroups.com/2011-04/msg00227.html and the link to the php code is here http://www.ovaistariq.net/27/youtube-batch-processing-requests-made-less-costly/. but you need to download the zip file. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an api request that looks like this:

```
<feed>
<batch:operation type="query"/>
<entry>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/123</id>
</entry>
<entry>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/456</id>
</entry>
</feed>
```

If you include multiple entries in the request, you'll get back multiple video info.

Comment: thanks for seeing in to this, this is what i have been trying to figure out is how do i use the API to make this request?

Answer (score 0):

> Always two there are; no more, no less.  A request and a response.

This is internet 101: one http request always yields one http response. If you want more than one video, you must send more than one request.  You can hide this from your users by running the requests in a loop or even in parallel, and only showing results after all have completed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoom, Hi Joel thank you for your RESPONSE lol. I understand, this is what i am currently doing in the application one request at a time, but requesting about 24 videos takes about 6 seconds and i want to display more than 24 videos maybe even display 50 videos. But what i do not understand is that if you query YouTube via a search item the feed can retrieve more than 1 video so why cant you query more than one video?